# minimax c++ implementation for tic tac toe

Tags: c++, brute-force, minimax

```
void generate_moves(int gameBoard[9], list<int> &moves)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
   {
        if (gameBoard[i] == 0){
            moves.push_back(i);
        }
   }
}



 int evaluate_position(int gameBoard[9], int playerTurn)        
 {
   state currentGameState = checkWin(gameBoard);

   if (currentGameState != PLAYING)
    {
       if ((playerTurn == 1 && currentGameState == XWIN) || (playerTurn == -1 && currentGameState == OWIN))
          return +infinity;
       else if ((playerTurn == -1 && currentGameState == XWIN) || (playerTurn == 1 && currentGameState == OWIN))
          return -infinity;
       else if (currentGameState == DRAW)
            return 0;
   }

     return -1;
  }




 int MinMove(int gameBoard[9], int playerTurn)
 {
     //if (checkWin(gameBoard) != PLAYING) { return evaluate_board(gameBoard); };
    int pos_val = evaluate_position(gameBoard, playerTurn);
     if (pos_val != -1) return pos_val;

     int bestScore = +infinity;
     list<int> movesList;
     generate_moves(gameBoard, movesList);

     while (!movesList.empty())
     {
         gameBoard[movesList.front()] = playerTurn;
         int score = MaxMove(gameBoard, playerTurn*-1); 
         if (score < bestScore)
         {
            bestScore = score;
         }
         gameBoard[movesList.front()] = 0;
         movesList.pop_front();
     }

    return bestScore;
 }



  int MaxMove(int gameBoard[9], int playerTurn)
  {
     //if (checkWin(gameBoard) != PLAYING) { return evaluate_board(gameBoard); };
     int pos_val = evaluate_position(gameBoard, playerTurn);
     if (pos_val != -1) return pos_val;

      int bestScore = -infinity;
      list<int> movesList;
      generate_moves(gameBoard, movesList);

      while (!movesList.empty())
      {
         gameBoard[movesList.front()] = playerTurn;
         int score = MinMove(gameBoard, playerTurn*-1);
         if (score > bestScore)
         {
             bestScore = score;
         }
         gameBoard[movesList.front()] = 0;
         movesList.pop_front();
       }

      return bestScore;
  }


  int MiniMax(int gameBoard[9], int playerTurn)
  {
     int bestScore = -infinity;
     int index = 0;
     list<int> movesList;
     vector<int> bestMoves;
     generate_moves(gameBoard, movesList);

     while (!movesList.empty())
     {
          gameBoard[movesList.front()] = playerTurn;
          int score = MinMove(gameBoard, playerTurn);
          if (score > bestScore)
          {
             bestScore = score;
             bestMoves.clear();
             bestMoves.push_back(movesList.front());
          }
          else if (score == bestScore)
          {
             bestMoves.push_back(movesList.front());
          }
        gameBoard[movesList.front()] = 0;
        movesList.pop_front();
     }

    index = bestMoves.size();
    if (index > 0) {
        time_t secs;
        time(&secs);
        srand((uint32_t)secs);
        index = rand() % index;
     }

    return bestMoves[index];
  }
```

I created a tic tac toe program in C++ and tried to implement a MiniMax algorithm with exhaustive search tree. 
These are the functions I have written using wiki and with the help of some websites. But the AI just doesn't work right and at times doesn't play its turn at all.

Could someone have a look and please point out if there is anything wrong with the logic?

This is how I think it works:

`Minimax` : This function starts with very large -ve number as best score and goal is to maximize that number. It calls `minMove` function. If new score > best score, then best score = new score...

`MinMove` : This function evaluates game board. If game over then it returns -infinity or +infinity depending on who won. If game is going on this function starts with max +infinity value as best score and goal is to minimize it as much possible. It calls `MaxMove` with opponent player's turn. (since players alternate turns). 
If score < best score then best score = score. ...

`MaxMove` : This function evaluates game board. If game over then it returns -infinity or +infinity depending on who won. If game is going on this function starts with least -infinity value as best score and goal is to maximize it as much possible. It calls `MinMove` with opponent player's turn. (since players alternate turns). 
If score > best score then best score = score. ...

`Minmove` and `MaxMove` call each other mutually recursively, `MaxMove` maximizing the value and `MinMove` minimizing it. Finally it returns the best possible moves list.

If there are more than 1 best moves, then a random of them is picked as the computer's move.

Comment: [OT]: You should call this only once `srand((uint32_t)secs);` (in main).

Comment: In addition to not seeding the prng everytime, prefer `<random>` to C `rand()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `MiniMax`, `MinMove(gameBoard, playerTurn)` should be `MinMove(gameBoard, -playerTurn)` as you do in `MaxMove`.

As you use `MinMove` and `MaxMove`, your evaluation function should be absolute. I mean `+infinity` for `XWIN`
and `-infinity` for `OWIN`. And so `MinMove` can only be use when `player == -1` and MaxMove when `player == 1`, thus the parameter become useless. And so `MiniMax` can only be used by `player == 1`.

I have done some changes in your code and it works (https://ideone.com/Ihy1SR).

Comment: The code you posted works. Your explanation helped me understand. 
Just one question...
Why is MaxMove used to return -ve? Is it because since O is a minimizing player it'll always evaluate -ve AND we need a positive score to compare with bestScore(which in this case is -infinity)?

Comment: @ChandanPednekar: Sorry, I don't understand your question, can you clarify ?